# Salesforce Checkmarx Integration

Tags: checkmarx

We need to setup the CheckMarx code scanner eclipse plug-in for Salesforce org.
While scanning from eclipse we are getting the server connection error massage :
1. We have downloaded the CxSAST installation package (http://www.checkmarx.com/downloads) but not able to run the exe file.
2. Could you please help us on this .

Comment: Have you got an account setup with Checkmarx and the account configured as at the 1:48 mark of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wcGp5jbrsE?

Answer (score 0):

The security scans done through security.force.com are managed by SFDC security team. 
Please contact them at securecloud@salesforce.com / sourcescanner@salesforce.com

Thank you!